# java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: view-source Exception problem

Tags: java, android-studio

**I'm trying to access an URL's content in android studio(java) but it gives "java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: view-source" exception! and i get result as failed.Please tell me how to Fix it!**

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result=null;
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
        try {
            url=new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in=urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data=  reader.read();
            while (data!=-1)
            {
                char current= (char) data;
                result= result+current;
                data=reader.read();

            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
            return "failed";
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: The short answer is get rid of the `view-source:` from the URL.  It is not recognized ... or meaningful ... in this context.

Answer (score 0):

HttpURLConnection is used for http protocol.May be your input url is not this protocol.Please ensure your input url is correct.